# Can I make spring actuator library calls to get health/metrics instead of using actuator endpoints?If yes , How?

Tags: spring-boot

Have a spring boot microservice which has to expose an endpoint for Kubernetes readiness probe. For this purpose , my microservice has to get metrics(memory,cpu,thread dumps etc) of itself and validate them against the threshold values and return 200(if success) or failure responses. I want to know if spring actuators have libraries which can do method calls to get health/metrics instead of using actuator endpoints

Comment: Have you looked at the kubernetes CPU and memory requests and limits features? Kubernetes can watch what the Pod is using for those particular metrics. Readiness is normally just about whether the Pod can serve business requests. The low-level stats you mention aren't normally part of readiness

Comment: If you're seeing Pods get OOMKilled then check the jvm parameters. If you're seeing some Pods get overwhelmed by requests then check your limits and look at how the HorizontalPodAutoscaler uses metrics.